# How would I send data from a post route to a get route in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, backend

I want to send data for products from my post request

```
router.post("/addProduct",(req, res) => {
    const {addName, addDescription, addPrice, addImg} = req.body;
    console.log(`${addName} added, the price is ${addPrice}`)
})
```

into the get request

```
router.get("/addProduct",(req, res) => {

    //console.log(`getting ${addName}, and the price is ${addPrice}`)
    console.log(`getting the response ${addName}`)
    
})
```

i want to send the const {addName, addDescription, addPrice, addImg} = req.body; into the get request, but I haven't found a lot of info on how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it's against the convention.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(router);

router.get("/addProduct", (req, res) => {
  const { addName } = req.body;
  console.log(`getting the response ${addName}`);
  return res.json(addName);
});

app.listen(3000, (req, res) => {
  console.log("listening...");
});
```